# Add space at left side

Tags: css

How I can add empty space at the left side of the text?

https://jsfiddle.net/ydL4emkd/

```
.camera_caption {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 717px;
  padding: 10px 20% 10px 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.camera_caption:before,
.camera_caption:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: -15%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}
.camera_caption:before {
  top: 0px;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
.camera_caption:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

I need to get this visual result:

[image]

Comment: Change the left padding to something like `padding: 10px 20% 10px 5%;`

Comment: just increase your left padding. E.g padding: `30px 20% 10px 10px;`

Comment: and add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the container if you don't want the padding to affect the width.

Answer (score 2):

Add more padding to the left

```
.camera_caption {
 ....
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-left`

```css
.camera_caption {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 717px;
  padding: 10px 20% 10px 70px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.camera_caption:before,
.camera_caption:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: -15%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}
.camera_caption:before {
  top: 0px;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}
.camera_caption:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="camera_caption">Some text</div>

<div class="camera_caption">Some text
  <br>spanning across
  <br>multiple line</div>

<div class="camera_caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas varius eros id consequat tempor. Nunc non libero nisi. Curabitur ultricies, magna eget hendrerit viverra, nibh leo faucibus est, eget efficitur mauris purus ut libero. Ut in arcu in leo
  ornare tristique. Quisque rutrum lectus a lorem sollicitudin porta. Etiam placerat felis metus, non luctus felis placerat et. Nam lacinia libero enim, ut placerat mi accumsan eget. Ut viverra ipsum sit amet leo gravida, ac consequat ligula consequat.
  Etiam consequat ex a augue rutrum, sed convallis est volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi pretium sem nec ipsum sollicitudin facilisis. Maecenas accumsan eleifend neque sit amet ornare. Curabitur condimentum arcu at tellus ullamcorper pretium. Mauris
  lorem nisl, pulvinar eu lectus tincidunt, luctus fringilla diam.</div>
```